# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_sql_query'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

As per the documentation, I have used the pandas module:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas

conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\sqlite\water-filter.db')
query = pandas.read_sql_query('select * from clients;', conn)
print(query)
```

The error I'm getting is:

> module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_sql_query'

EDIT : The pandas module works in the interpreter, but doesn't when I save it  in as a .py file

Comment: What does printing out `pandas.__version__` tell you?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it gives me AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '__version__'. I installed pandas on my machine just a few minutes ago with pip tool

Comment: @IrfanSindhi, are you using any sort of IDE that needs to be reloaded with the most up-to-downloaded modules? Perhaps you have another version of Python installed that pip installed to the not-expected version. Also as every IT professional has asked me "have you tried turning it on and off again?"

Comment: @IrfanSindhi what does `pandas.__file__` show you?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ oh okay, I got my version: `0.21.0`

Comment: So it's fixed now is it?

Comment: This should work.

Comment: @JonClements Nope

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I saw some other SO posts for different attributes of pandas, and it said to go deep with the import. For example, `pandas.something.somthing`

Comment: Importing `pandas` imports everything else to the top level, so you can access as needed.

Comment: @Irfan umm... so that version looks reasonable... can you do `df = pandas.DataFrame()` without a problem ?

Comment: @JonClements  I see the problem. Pandas module works on the python interpreter, but not as a .py file. Why is that?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Check my edit

Comment: Is your file named `pandas.py`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Nope its `select.py`. I just changed my file name, and for some reason it works.

Comment: Is there _another_ file in your directory called `pandas.py`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It works now. I changed my file name from `select.py` to `random123.py` and works **Strange**